# Rails path helper inconsistency

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, routes

`new_photo_path` returns `/photos/new`.

However, the helper `awesome_photos_path` is created for `/photos/awesome` defined as:

```
resources :photos do
  collection do
    get 'awesome'
  end
end
```

This is annoying. Is there an easy way to ease the pain?

Comment: What's so painful about that? Seems logical to me.

Comment: I'd like both helpers to be singular or plural. Think about it. If I'm showing an awesome photo I'd like to refer to it as `awesome_photo`. Another example would be random. I'd want to link to `random_photo_path`.

Comment: If you want **a** awesome_photo, you should use `member do get 'awesome' end` instead. Collection is a bunch of photo**s**, so `awesome_photos` makes sense. (Consider `photos_path` vs `photo_path(@photo)`)

Comment: I know the difference between `member` and `collection`. You can image awesome photo to be the most favorited one, so it doesn't have a specific `:id`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
match "/photo/awesome" => "photos#awesome", :as => :awesome_photo
```

Comment: @m33lky: okay, removed it then :-)